# Oauth google in superset forces the user to type password an email

Tags: apache-superset

I enabled google login in Superset (currently using helmchart)
However each time a new user tries to login superset would request the user to type the email instead of showing currently logged in google users

How to enable such a feature?

current settings:

```
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        "name": "google",
        "whitelist": [ os.getenv("OAUTH_WHITELIST_REGEX", "") ],
        "icon": "fa-google",
        "token_key": "access_token",
        "remote_app": {
            "client_id": os.environ.get("GOOGLE_KEY"),
            "client_secret": os.environ.get("GOOGLE_SECRET"),
            "api_base_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/",
            "client_kwargs": {"scope": "email profile"},
            "request_token_url": None,
            "access_token_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "authorize_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "authorize_params": {"hd": os.getenv("OAUTH_HOME_DOMAIN", "")}
        }
    }
]
```